# How to make pandas.Series.str.split work with empty dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have following code splitting one column with values of form 'a-b' into two ones with values 'a' and 'b':

```
df[['name', 'value']] = df['value'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)
```

It works fine until `df` is empty when I get "Columns must be same length as key".

It there way to handle this condition flawlessly, without explicit check for emptiness?

Comment: Can you add one row of empty df with expected output?

Comment: Like `...split(..).append(pandas.DataFrame(columns=[0, 1], data[]))`?

Comment: Maybe understand, what need, changed answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think here is problem no separator in all values of `value` column, so output is only 1 column `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['', 'ab']})

print ( df['value'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True))
    0
0    
1  ab
```

If need always 2 columns DataFrame in output with filled first column add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `list=[1,0]`:

```
df[['name', 'value']] = df['value'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True).reindex([1,0], axis=1)
print (df)
  value  name
0         NaN
1    ab   NaN
```

---

If need to fill second column by data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['', 'ab']})

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[0,1])
df[['name', 'value']] = df['value'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True).append(df1)
print (df)
  value name
0   NaN     
1   NaN   ab
```

Or change list to `[0,1]` in [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['', 'ab']})

df[['name', 'value']] = df['value'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True).reindex([0,1], axis=1)
print (df)
   value name
0    NaN     
1    NaN   ab
```